# What is wrong with my proof that $x^Hy = x^Ty$ for any complex vectors $x,y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I must be crazy but I just could not find where is going wrong.

Given an inner product space $(V,<>)$ where $V=(F,V)$ is a vector space with scalar field $F$ and vector abelian group $V$ ($V$ is overloaded to represent both the vector space and abelian group).

The following is my note for "inner product matrix". This is my note so it might contain error.

> [image]
>   [image]

In above note I showed that fix a basis $\bf{V}$, if two inner products have the same inner product matrix with respect to $\bf{V}$, then the two inner products are the same (the so-called one-to-one correspondence).

However, consider vector space $(\Bbb C, \Bbb C^n)$ of complex numbers. The standard basis for $(\Bbb R, \Bbb R^n)$ (those vectors with only one component being 1 and other components being zero) is also a basis for $(\Bbb C, \Bbb C^n)$. For any vector $x\in {\Bbb C}^n$, let $x^H$ denote the transpose conjugate of $x$.

Define inner product $<>_1$ as $<x,y>_1=x^Ty$ and inner product $<>_2$ as $<x,y>_2=x^Hy$. The inner product matrices of the two inner products with respect to the "standard basis" seem to be identity matrix since it is orthogonal with respect to both inner products. Then I reach a strange result that the two inner products are the same and $x^Ty=x^Hy$ for any $x,y$, which is obviously wrong.

I don't know where did I go wrong in the above proof. Hope someone can help point it out. Thank you!

Comment: I think $x^Ty$ is not an inner product in $\mathbb{C}^n$ at first place. You showed that for a fixed vector space $V$, two inner products on $V$ that give the the same inner product  matrix are  the same inner products. But $x^Ty$ is not an inner product in $\mathbb{C}^n$, so your result does not apply.

Comment: $x^T y$ doesn't satisfy the positive definiteness of inner product.